# Populating jQuery Field Dynamically Depending on Rails Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

In my Rails (3.1) app, I have a shopping cart where I show the sales tax field and total on a page after the person enters their State.

It works correctly, except when there is an error and the person has already entered their State.  In that case, the field value doesn't change (since the State field is populated already), so the jQuery (update_sales_tax) isn't triggered again.

Is there a way to render the view again (in case of errors) so the person doesn't need to fill out the entire form again, but have the sales tax calculated still?  Or maybe a better approach to showing the user their sales tax on the page dynamically (since it's dependent on the State)?

In other words, my controller does this `format.html {render :action => 'new'}` if there is an error in Orders#new.  It populates the fields in the form that the person already entered, however it doesn't recalculate the sales tax which is triggered onChange of the :state field via jQuery.  How do I get this to recalculate if the view renders again and :state is already populated?

In the Orders#new view I have:

```
<%= form_for(@order,  :method => :post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :total_sales_tax, :value => @tax_amount  %>

    <%= f.fields_for :products_shipping do |shipping | %>       
      <%= shipping.select(:state , Order::STATES ,{:prompt => 'Select State'}, :id => "ship_state",:onchange => "update_sales_tax()") %>                                
    <% end %>               
<% end %>

<script>
  function update_sales_tax(){
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '/orders/order_update',
      dataType: 'script',
  type:'get',
  data:'stateTo='+jQuery("#ship_state").val()   
    })
}
 </script>
```

In orders/order_update.js.erb:

```
jQuery('#cart_details').html('<%=  escape_javascript(render(:partial => @cart)) %>');
jQuery('#order_amount').val('<%= format("%.2f", @grand_total) %>');
jQuery('#order_total_shipping').val('<%=  format("%.2f", @cart.total_shipping) %>');
jQuery('#order_total_sales_tax').val('<%=  format("%.2f", @tax_amount) %>');
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I cant understand!

Comment: OK, I added a new part "In other words..."

Comment: Im sorry. Let me guess what you are saying. Lets say you have 3 select dropdowns in a form. Country, State, City. Tell me what you want with this example.

Comment: No problem.  In that example, let's say that jQuery is triggered to calculate tax based onChange with State that works.  However, if a validation fails in Rails for that form, it will render that view again with the State field populated.  Therefore, the jQuery calculation will not take place because it is only triggered with onChange.

Comment: Im sorry again. Can you give screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just needed to add this line above the function:

```
window.onload = update_sales_tax();
```